# Vega Visualization where Data Element Name Contains At Symbol

Tags: vega

We have data created by an external source (i.e. I cannot just change the names used so it works) -- the datetime field is named @timestamp and I cannot figure out how to address that element within a transformation expression.

Sample data is available on [Vega.GitHub.IO](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAB3GgBN6aABwAGNTPg0yWNACYNMhXGgAnGjkztJ6AMpQk4gAQKkmJM-n1nTJBDgAGxpxOGkQHCQFBRCyNAEZa0xAsNRQTDgAD0w0EABZAE9nBydnABF3FBkAMzMkBFSQJjYGcQUIcKdYNjNciA8zHJk2auqAnNQARn0ZAC8Qk0y0NQBfY0q0AG1QcXrG6Cc3D3DiJECGUy30mgb%20%20pxcw319AFo1ARf9ADYAFUmBKZqKYAFkoAGYAJwCABa4QAAtZbh4EA90E9Xu9Pr9-oCQeCobCZIE2BAOlMwZQBAIVGtrkj7o81M83h9vn8AZMIVN9JQvhCVISQAibqZkaiQOiWVj2VMudNefzBcTSWhJhSqTSpHTRQy0UyMazsQDgVzgZNwcCwYLhfSUYzmZi2TiTagzRareFlWS1bywbSQIidXa9Q7DTKBAB2VACNS8vnWwN3YMS-VSp0AyPR2NfeOekne0H6Saa7VJ8WStRfT7Av5fEGAymK%20GJsX2jFV-Q1yZ1ybAhsCJtE-Oq2OTSYR-0t3Uph0drs9uvAr6UfQRgXNkVlttvOe1qaL5er9dDlUN4ERyaTzetkPt6t-OV1gTL4EaBPX6cV3ec-fRl9vvNT0mUdxxWABdRI6nECBqh6BArgDAocEaWCzAQBhAiqEAshwXp0COOBAwACiOBgEEoKcUQASk6MkAygmC4LgJQPztcD-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%20jGrXEcNi5cjIMw4Hu7zqsncnYowsIajG%20CwcWpp-CCEIwmh%2064YR%20b7uRxGzc11JQCtxoAGIvgEfQoAhNQ1bR0AMZALG4%20WaHBaz4XGnqsLxalmW6DlhW1rxjaVWhzJ9Ej4uQsunRdhp9BEuUU2Na13WkstwTUmBaG2EiKA6ELkA89QWM-SdrV-v2AoEGaGmZAgGAkHFqezCgEWPdBrKfZ4-3%20KD2H4ZjpHRsRzO-NbzHFfWgmyrQkmxLFxoMhRHozi0waAzOgb0WYIDZjADmXMEA8z5gXFuZwS4-1yBXY6VdrA12xkreuHQ%207mx1nrZKBsR4GHwdHYeRsIoMDMDgEWTt2JAA) and in a [Gist with the data](https://gist.github.com/ljr55555/8757308f243eaf894bd1314cb8550c44)  -- I added the "timestamp" element to verify the issue I am experiencing is related to the at sign in the name. Using the 'timestamp' data field, I am able to transform and graph the data as desired:

[image: This works fine if the data element is named 'timestamp']

But I have been unable to use the @timestamp field. I get a parse failure if I use  `"expr": "datetime(datum.@timestamp)"` and an invalid date if I use `"expr": "datetime('datum.@timestamp')"`. Attempting to escape the at sign (or the quotes) gives me parse errors as well. How exactly can I use the data element named `@timestamp` in the expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out -- I don't think it has anything to do with Vega but, rather, is a JavaScript limitation. I can use the array subscript method of accessing the data and the dates parse.

[image]